# NoSuchMethod Errors Inside Repository & Data Sources Classes While Using FlutterSecureStorage Package

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, dart-null-safety

I am trying to persist the user authentication state of an already working auth system using `flutter_bloc and Nodejs`, by storing my successfully retrieved and generated JWTs. I have chosen `flutter_secure_storage (FSS), for brevity` as my key-value cache system.

Whenever I try to read or write data with `FSS`, I keep running into these kind of errors:

```
Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'write/read/delete' was called on null.
```

In the case of writing my JWTs to FSS, here's an example snippet:

```
@override
Future<UserModel> loginUser(Map<String, dynamic> body) async {
final userModel = await dataSource.loginUser(body);
var userId = userModel.id;
Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () async {
  await storage.write(key: APIConstants.USER_ID_KEY, value: userId);
});
return userModel;
```

}

Have even tried delaying the `write` operation to see if the value will save, it only logs me in cos of proper credentials and then throws an error, not crashing though, that's great.

Here's the `data source` class snippet for login user:

```
abstract class UserRemoteDataSource {
  Future<UserModel> loginUser(Map<String, dynamic> body);
  Future<UserModel> registerUser(Map<String, dynamic> body);
  // Future<User> sendOTP();
  // Future<User> verifyOTP();
  Future<UserModel> getCurrentUser(String userId);
  Future<void> logOut();
}

class UserRemoteDataSourceImpl implements UserRemoteDataSource {

  final APIClient client;
  var storage = FlutterSecureStorage();
  UserRepository repository;
  UserRemoteDataSourceImpl({@required this.client});

  @override
  Future<UserModel> loginUser(Map<String, dynamic> body) async {
    final response = await client.postAuthData('login', body);
    final userResponseModel = UserResponseModel.fromJSON(response);

  final accessToken = userResponseModel.accessToken;
  final refreshToken = userResponseModel.refreshToken;

  storage = FlutterSecureStorage();
  await storage.write(key: APIConstants.ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY, value: accessToken)
        .then((value) => print('AccessToken Written to FSS')); // this callback from future logs, so I know that the tokens have been saved
  await storage.write(key: APIConstants.REFRESH_TOKEN_KEY, value: refreshToken)
        .then((value) => print('RefreshToken Written to FSS'));

  return userResponseModel.user;
}

 @override
 Future<UserModel> registerUser(Map<String, dynamic> body) async {
   final response = await client.postAuthData('register', body);
   final userResponseModel = UserResponseModel.fromJSON(response);

   final accessToken = userResponseModel.accessToken;
   final refreshToken = userResponseModel.refreshToken;

   storage = FlutterSecureStorage();
   await storage.write(key: APIConstants.ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY, value: accessToken)
      .then((value) => print('AccessToken Written to FSS'));
   await storage.write(key: APIConstants.REFRESH_TOKEN_KEY, value: refreshToken)
      .then((value) => print('AccessToken Written to FSS'));

   return userResponseModel.user;
 }

 @override
 Future<UserModel> getCurrentUser(String id) {
   return null; // cos of write and read operation for userid, had to just return null for now
 }

 @override
 Future<void> logOut() async {
  await client.postAuthData('logout', null);
 }
```

}

Now, when I compile my code, cos of the `Delayed Future in Repository Snippet (First One Above)`, I get this error (showing full logs):

```
I/flutter ( 5048): Login state is LoginStateInitial
I/flutter ( 5048): LoginState Listened is:  LoginStateLoading
I/flutter ( 5048): LoginState Building is:  LoginStateLoading
I/flutter ( 5048): {success: true, message: Logged in Successfully, user: {_id: 60435f3a0b5da10015bb87b3, username: abc123, email: abc123@gmail.com, password: $2b$10$wgdBFyvWUI4e0bB3KNRBl.WLLVwu2FVZQN9BtSSdxbSzfcwdQyH2K, phone: 89066060484, __v: 0}, accessToken: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE2MTgxMjU2NTEsImV4cCI6MTYyMDcxNzY1MSwiYXVkIjoiNjA0MzVmM2EwYjVkYTEwMDE1YmI4N2IzIiwiaXNzIjoicGlja3VycGFnZS5jb20ifQ.uH3D_v6mYwIOnBgRfoQQYzrN8asPt_Rhfei9wxmAM6A, refreshToken: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE2MTgxMjU2NTEsImV4cCI6MTY0OTY4MzI1MSwiYXVkIjoiNjA0MzVmM2EwYjVkYTEwMDE1YmI4N2IzIiwiaXNzIjoicGlja3VycGFnZS5jb20ifQ.dIgOHlsXdBXUtrLNqiF3mKhmKZU0HJe-IwMDyg23OO0}
D/FlutterSecureStoragePl( 5048): Initializing StorageCipher
I/fluttersecurestorage( 5048): Creating keys!
I/fluttersecurestorage( 5048): Initializing
I/fluttersecurestorage( 5048): Generating key pair
E/KeyStore( 5048): generateKeyInternal failed on request -68
D/FlutterSecureStoragePl( 5048): StorageCipher initialization complete
D/FlutterSecureStoragePl( 5048): StorageCipher already initialized
I/flutter ( 5048): LoginState Listened is:  LoginStateSuccess
W/utter_bloc_aut( 5048): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;- 
>compareAndSwapObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z (greylist, linking, allowed)
E/flutter ( 5048): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: 
   // starts from here // NoSuchMethodError: The method 'write' was called on null.
E/flutter ( 5048): Receiver: null
E/flutter ( 5048): Tried calling: write(key: "userId", value: "60435f3a0b5da10015bb87b3") // in repository file
E/flutter ( 5048): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
E/flutter ( 5048): #1      UserRepositoryImpl.loginUser.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_bloc_auth/data/repositories/user_repository_impl.dart:22:21)
E/flutter ( 5048): #2      UserRepositoryImpl.loginUser.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_bloc_auth/data/repositories/user_repository_impl.dart:21:42)
E/flutter ( 5048): #3      new Future.delayed.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:315:39)
```

Is this a prime example of using `null safety` and how? I had previously tried migrating the entire project to null safety but there were cyclic dependencies on the packages, so I continued without null safety.

Is this a case of using `FutureBuilder` to wait for the value of the strings (tokens and userid). Had tried calling `.then` but my response body (JSON String) is not a Future, obviously.

What's the cause of this error as we can see it later held the value of `userId` in `E/flutter ( 5048): Tried calling: write(key: "userId", value: "60435f3a0b5da10015bb87b3")` but initially it didn't, as per my understanding.

I've run into this error severally and still haven't found a way to deal with it. Any help will be appreciated.

```
                   --------EDIT (SIMILAR ISSUE)------
```

I've gotten the tokens and userid to save when login method is called. However, when I close the app and re-open it, it throws an error for reading the access token key (which was saved previously), like below log:

```
I/flutter (27570): AuthenticationStateInitial
I/flutter (27570): LoginState Building is:  LoginStateInitial
I/flutter (27570): NoSuchMethodError: The method 'read' was called on null.
I/flutter (27570): Receiver: null
I/flutter (27570): Tried calling: read(key: "access_token")
I/flutter (27570): AuthenticationStateFailure
```

I want the AuthenticationBloc to read the state once it finds the token as Authenticated not Failure, each time a previously logged in or just signed up user opens the app. What's the best strategy for that?

Here's my `AuthenticationBloc` snippet. Login & Register Blocs Snippets Skipped Due to Brevity and Similarity of Functionality.

```
class AuthenticationBloc
extends Bloc<AuthenticationEvent, AuthenticationState> {

  final UserRepository _repository;
  AuthenticationBloc(UserRepository repository)
  : assert(repository != null), _repository = repository,
    super(AuthenticationStateInitial());

  @override
  Stream<AuthenticationState> mapEventToState(
    AuthenticationEvent event) async* {

    if (event is AppStarted) {
      yield* _mapAppStartedToState(event);
    }

    if(event is UserSignedUp){
      yield* _mapUserSignedUpToState(event);
    }

    if(event is UserLoggedIn){
      yield* _mapUserLoggedInToState(event);
    }

    if(event is UserLoggedOut){
      await _repository.deleteTokens(event.accessToken, event.refreshToken);
      yield* _mapUserLoggedOutToState(event);
    }

  }

  Stream<AuthenticationState> _mapAppStartedToState(AppStarted event) async* 
    {
      yield AuthenticationStateLoading();
      try{
       // if(event?.accessToken == null || event.refreshToken == null) {
      //   yield AuthenticationStateUnAuthenticated();
      // } else {
     //   print('accessToken is\t${event?.accessToken}');
      //   print('refreshToken is\t${event?.refreshToken}');
     //   try {
     //     final currentUser = await _repository.getCurrentUser();
     //     yield AuthenticationStateAuthenticated(user: currentUser, );
    //   } catch(error2) {
    //     print(error2);
    //   }
    // }

    final hasTokens = await _repository.checkHasTokens(event.accessToken, event.refreshToken); //simple read operation using the Keys used to write tokens values
    print('hasTokens $hasTokens');
    final currentUser = await _repository.getCurrentUser();
    // if(hasTokens && currentUser != null){
    if(hasTokens){
      yield AuthenticationStateAuthenticated(user: currentUser, );
    } else {
      yield AuthenticationStateUnAuthenticated();
    }
  } catch(err){
    print(err);
   // yield AuthenticationStateFailure(errorMessage: err.message ?? 'Error Completing Your Request, Try Again!');
    yield AuthenticationStateFailure(errorMessage: 'Error Completing Your Request, Try Again!');
  }
}

Stream<AuthenticationState> _mapUserSignedUpToState(UserSignedUp event) async* {
  yield AuthenticationStateAuthenticated(user: event.user);
}

Stream<AuthenticationState> _mapUserLoggedInToState(UserLoggedIn event) async* {
  yield AuthenticationStateAuthenticated(user: event.user);
}

Stream<AuthenticationState> _mapUserLoggedOutToState(UserLoggedOut event) async* {
  await _repository.logOut();
  yield AuthenticationStateUnAuthenticated();
}
```

}

and `UserRepositoryImpl` Snippet, as Suggested:

```
class UserRepositoryImpl extends UserRepository {

final UserRemoteDataSource dataSource;
UserRepositoryImpl({@required this.dataSource});

var storage;

@override
  Future<UserModel> loginUser(Map<String, dynamic> body) async {
  final userModel = await dataSource.loginUser(body);
  // var userId = userModel.id;
  // Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () async {
//   await storage.write(key: APIConstants.USER_ID_KEY, value: userId);
// });
  return userModel;
}

@override
 Future<UserModel> registerUser(Map<String, dynamic> body) async {
  final userModel = await dataSource.registerUser(body);
 // await storage.write(key: APIConstants.USER_ID_KEY, value: userModel.id);
  return userModel;
}

@override
 Future<UserModel> getCurrentUser() async {
  // final userId = await storage.read(key: APIConstants.USER_ID_KEY);
  // final user = await dataSource.getCurrentUser(userId);
  // return user;
 return null;
}

@override
Future<void> logOut() async {
  storage = FlutterSecureStorage();
  await storage.delete(key: APIConstants.ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY);
  await storage.write(key: APIConstants.REFRESH_TOKEN_KEY);
  await dataSource.logOut();
}

@override
Future<void> saveTokens(String accessToken, String refreshToken) async {
  final storage = FlutterSecureStorage();
  print('st() accesstokenval\t:$accessToken');
  await storage.write(key: APIConstants.ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY, value: accessToken);
  await storage.write(key: APIConstants.REFRESH_TOKEN_KEY, value: refreshToken);
}

@override
Future<void> deleteTokens(String accessToken, String refreshToken) async {
  storage = FlutterSecureStorage();
  await storage.delete(key: APIConstants.ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY);
  await storage.write(key: APIConstants.REFRESH_TOKEN_KEY);
}

@override
Future<bool> checkHasTokens(String accessToken, String refreshToken) async{
  storage = FlutterSecureStorage();
  final hasAT = await storage.read(key: APIConstants.ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY);
  final hasRT = await storage.read(key: APIConstants.REFRESH_TOKEN_KEY);
  return hasRT == null || hasAT == null ? false : true;
}
```

}

Comment: Could you show us the user_repository_impl class and it's loginUser() method ?

Comment: I have fixed this error. Everything works but not so great, like instead of directly taking the user to home page, it briefly displays the login page. Thanks